# sha256 : How to use the algorithm as input

Tags: c#, hash

Ok here is my problem.  I know how to HASH using C#, I made this function to Hash Files and provide progress bar:

```
   public String SHA384CheckSum(String pstrFilePath)
    {
        const Int32 BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = (4 * 1024 * 1000);  //4Mo
        String strRetValue = "";
        String strBaseCaption = this.Text;
        Int64 dblProgression1;
        Int64 dblProgression2 = 0;

        this.Text = strBaseCaption + " [0%]";

        //Should check if file exist first
        if (AppEx.FileExist64(pstrFilePath) == true)
        {
            //using (SHA384 objSHA = SHA384.Create())
            using (SHA384 objSHA = SHA384.Create()) {
                using (FileStream objFileStream = new FileStream(pstrFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    Int32 _bufferSize;
                    Byte[] readAheadBuffer;
                    Int32 readAheadBytesRead;
                    Int64 lngBytesRemaining = objFileStream.Length;
                    Double dblTotalBytes = lngBytesRemaining;

                    while ((lngBytesRemaining > 0) && (this.glngState != 2))
                    {
                        if (lngBytesRemaining > BUFFER_MAX_SIZE)
                        {
                            _bufferSize = BUFFER_MAX_SIZE;
                        } else {
                            _bufferSize = (Int32)lngBytesRemaining;
                        }

                        readAheadBuffer = new Byte[_bufferSize];
                        readAheadBytesRead = objFileStream.Read(readAheadBuffer, 0, _bufferSize);

                        lngBytesRemaining = (lngBytesRemaining - _bufferSize);
                        if (lngBytesRemaining != 0)
                        {
                            objSHA.TransformBlock(readAheadBuffer, 0, readAheadBytesRead, readAheadBuffer, 0);
                        } else {
                            objSHA.TransformFinalBlock(readAheadBuffer, 0, readAheadBytesRead);
                            strRetValue = BitConverter.ToString(objSHA.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                        }

                        dblProgression1 = (Int64)(((dblTotalBytes - lngBytesRemaining) / dblTotalBytes) * 100);
                        if (dblProgression1 != dblProgression2)
                        {
                            dblProgression2 = dblProgression1;
                            this.Text = strBaseCaption + " [" + dblProgression2.ToString() + "%]";
                            Application.DoEvents();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.Text = strBaseCaption + " [100%]";

        return strRetValue;
    }
```

This work perfectly.  Now let's suppose I want to hash using Sha256 instead.  All I have to do is change this line:

```
    using (SHA384 objSHA = SHA384.Create())
    to
    using (SHA256 objSHA = SHA256.Create())
    
    How can I pass this as a parameter to the function so I could:
    SHA256 objSHA;
    or
    SHA384 objSHA

and then CALL The Function (..., objSHA)
```

seem simple enough because they are both abstract class coming from the same type.
but I lack the knowledge to do that in C#.

thanks for help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_Create_System_String_ ?

Comment: I personally think you should separate your concerns, You have UI logic mixed with business logic mixed hash logic

Comment: _"I lack the knowledge to do that in C#"_ -- lack the knowledge to do _what_? There are actually a number of different ways you could approach the problem, involving different parts of the language, such as the type system, method parameters, conditional statements, lambda expressions, etc. What _specifically_ are you trying to do, and what _specifically_ do you need help with? Please read [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Peter: The question is HOW to pass the parameter, it's in clear text

Comment: You need to put `@` before a person's user ID, if you want them to be notified about a response.

Comment: _"it's in clear text"_ -- I assure you, it's not. Even your comment isn't clear. _What_ parameter are you trying to pass? What have you tried already? What _specifically_ have you not been able to figure out? Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site. You're expected to avail yourself of existing resources, including the language documentation, so that you at least understand fundamental programming concepts related to your problem. And your question needs to provide details about what you _do_ understand and what specifically is blocking you.

Answer (score -1):

Make your method receive the base class as a parameter:

```
public String SHA384CheckSum(String pstrFilePath, HashAlgorithm objSHA)
```

Now your calling code can invoke it like so:

```
bool useSha256 = false; // Initialize this any way you want
using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = useSha256 ? (HashAlgorithm)SHA256.Create() : SHA384.Create())
{
    string checksum = SHA384CheckSum(pstrFilePath, algorithm);
}
```

Obviously, `SHA384CheckSum` is no longer a good name for this function, so the next step is to rename it.

Comment: the using line doesn't work I got:      Error CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256' and 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384'

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you made me found the solution.  I passed the HashAlgorithmType, then I made a Switch case for all HashAlgorithmType (using default for SHA384) then inside each case I made the  Create function.  of course I had to remove the using, but I made a dispose at end.  so all working now and I can pass any hashing type.

Comment: @PatriceCharbonneau - The problem I forgot was that if you have a conditional expression, you have to explicitly cast the first item in the expression. (See my changed code above, where I cast the return value of `SHA256.Create()` to its base class.